# MySQL EF Core all string fields are create as text columns

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When generating my Tables using Entity Framework Core for MySQL all of the string properties are being created as text columns in MySQL

I am using:

```
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data" Version="8.0.8-*" />
<PackageReference Include="MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.8-*" />
```

I am trying to use the built in Identity authentication in .net and when I generate the tables I get the error:

```
BLOB/TEXT column 'NormalizedEmail' used in key specification without a key length
```

I can work around this by adding:

```
builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(i => i.NormalizedName)
                                  .HasColumnType("varchar(256)");
```

But I don't want to do this for every column in the Identity Model nor do I really want columns I add like FirstName being stored as a text column.

Is this a bug in EF Core for MySQL or do I have some configuration wrong?

Comment: That's the way it's supposed to be. Only if you have limitation in place (MaxLength/.HasMaxLength), then a var char may be chosen. For all other cases you have to override/specify it yourself

Comment: Looking at what is generated in the Migration Snapshot it is being specified with a Max Length but still being created as a text field                   `b.Property<string>("NormalizedUserName").HasMaxLength(256);`

Comment: I tried version `7.0.7-*` of both MySql.Data and MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore and the columns that were generated as text columns are generated as varchar(255).  I will just stick with 7.0.7 until I get a better answer.

Comment: Try Pomelo MySQL Provider, its more stable and has true async. Oracles provider doesn't use true async (it uses sync over async, so no benefits in terms of using async), so you won't get any benefits from freeing the request thread during async operations anyways

Comment: Thanks @Tseng I switched to Pomelo and all seems to work now.  I initially tried 7.0.7 but seemed to run into an issue with async. Pomelo solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tseng for the recommendation of using Pomelo. It was a simple switch and it solved all of my problems.